# What is the enzyme production rate of a single E. Coli bacterium?

Tags: enzymes, transcription, plasmids, computational-model

Suppose an E.Coli bacterium intakes a plasmid which encodes for an enzyme, if the promoter strength is known, is is possible to predict the rate at which the enzyme is produced? Is there an equation which could model such a process?